# Defined $X,Y,Z,W$ find $P(W=0)$ and $P(W=X)$

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are iid binary random variables satisfying $P(X=0)=P(Y=0)=P(Z=0)=0.5$ and define a new random variable $W$ as $W=X$ if $Z=0$ and $W=Y$ if $Z=1$. Then find $P(W=0)$ and $P(W=X)$.

I just wanted the community to see that my solution is correct. This came in an exam in my university that my friends are giving various answers.

> $P(W=0)=P(W=0,Z=0)+P(W=0,Z=1)=P(W=0|Z=0)P(Z=0)+P(W=0|Z=1)P(Z=1)=P(X=0)P(Z=0)+P(Y=0)P(Z=1)=0.5^2+0.5^2=0.5$
>
> $P(W=X)=P(W=X,Z=0)+P(W=X,Z=1)=P(W=X|Z=0)P(Z=0)+P(W=Y|Z=1)P(Z=1)=P(Z=0)+P(W=X=Y)P(Z=1)=P(Z=0)+P(X=Y)P(Z=1)=0.5+0.5\times0.5=0.75$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

$P(W=0) = P(W=0|Z=0) P(Z=0) + P(W=0 | Z=1) P(Z=1) = P(X=0) P(Z=0) + P(Y=0) P(Z=1) = 1/2$

$P(W=X) = P(W=X | Z=0) P(Z=0) + P(W=X|Z=1) P(Z=1) = 1*P(Z=0) + P(Y=X) P(Z=1) = 3/4$ because$P(Y=X)=1/2$ since $Y=X$ occurs for $X=Y=0,X=Y=1$ and not for $X=0, Y=1$ or $X=1,Y=0$ all of which are equiprobable

Comment: Sorry but only the last line is not copied from the question, right?

Comment: None of the lines match the question, in fact.

Comment: Huh? $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: I wrote the answer down on my own. And you'll see that I went directly to using the law of total probability in conditional form rather than how OP did it.

Comment: My first comment does not mention copy-pasting but that the answer between "You are correct." and "P(Y=X)=1/2" reproduces the question.